# SQL Nested set table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using Nested Set for my Continents, Countries, Regions and Cities table.

Now I am facing a problem that one country can belong to multiple continents and similarly one city can be divided into 2 different regions.

What will be the best possible solution to solve such issue?

Is there any possiblity to add multiple parents for a child without breaking the Nested Sets pattern?

I mean with `left` and `right` column infos?

Comment: If I understand correctly, with Nested Sets you look if the start of a child is between the start and stop of a parent.  And those parents normally don't have overlapping start & stop. But what if 2 parents do have an overlapping start & stop and the child's start is between the overlapping range? Maybe you could add some simplified sample data & expected output.

Comment: However, if that works without breaking the pattern that would only allow a child to belong to 2 parents. Not 3 or more. So not what you want.

Comment: You can split the cities and countries into parts and have logic *outside* the nested set model that combines them into a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

so when you are saying there is possibility of the above statement, where on city/continents can belong to multiple parents. it became

> Many to Many (* to *)

And in case of that best approach is having third table between parent-child.

Table - CountryContinentRel

> CountryId   |   ContinentId

it is enough flexible to accept your 1 to many and many to many relationship.